# Wordpress Hook for user account activation in normal Wp (not MU)

Tags: plugin-development

what is the action hook, if a user activates his profile? For the profile update, it is:

```
profile_update
```

for example. My goal is, to execute a function, if a user activates his profile. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'user_activate','my_function');
```

Comment: have you already taken a look at the core files? A simple cross-file search for `do_action(` will surely help ,)

Comment: if its not multisite there is no activation by default unless you are using some kind of plugin. what plugins are  you using

Comment: @bainternet Currently I dot use any Plugins. Only Reguster Plus Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there you go Register Plus Redux is the plugin which is adding your new user verification, and by looking at its code there are no filters or hooks which is said because if you make changes to it they will be lost the next time you update, so i would suggest to contact the plugin developer and ask him to add it.

But a quick fix for you would be to add

```
do_action('3cees_user_activate',$user_id);
```

after line 2938 at register-plus-redux.php

and you can then call it like this:

```
add_action( '3cees_user_activate','your_function');
```

and your function will run when a user is activated and $user_id will be passed to it.

Comment: What shall I say? A great answer. Many Thanks to you.

Comment: ..hmmmm...the files only has 2627 lines of code. Did you look in the latest version?

Comment: Yep my bad, i was looking at the development version,  in the perestroika stable version add the line of code at line 2462